# JPA Hibernate, Persist 3 layers

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to persist data 3 layers deep with JPA Hibernate.

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| B | D |

A.Java

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<B> b;
```

B.Java

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "b_id")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private D d;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "c_id")
  private C c;
```

C.Java

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;
```

Only A, B, D are getting saved and not C. Where am I going wrong

Edit 1 :
For persisting, I create a model of A and have a repository

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, String> {    
}

private final ARepository repository;
A model = new A();
repository.save(A)
```

Comment: what is the code that does the actual persisting?

Comment: @Stultuske, Updated the post with sample code snippet